# Excel setting one cell value based on a a date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering is somebody could help me with this problem, I have a spreadsheet like the one below.

I need a cell to equal the next payment number if the date is between to dates. So for example if today was the 20th January then the cell b2 would be 3 as the 1st  Feb is the next payment number.

I was able to highlight a cell with conditional formatting for the next payment date, but this time I want cell b2 = the next payment number based on todays date.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this
[image: Excel]

Thanks in advance

David :)

Comment: Are the dates in column C in date format or just text?

Answer (score 0):

If you get the dates in column C in date format you can use this formula:

```
=INDEX(B5:B11,MATCH(Today(),C4:C11,1))
```

Comment: Yes, They are date ranges, and Yes that worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with that list, a formula like this could be used:

```
=COUNTIF(C4:C11,"<"&TODAY())+1
```

if it is allways the same like in your example, you also could use this formula:

```
=MONTH(TODAY())*2+(DAY(TODAY())>15)
```

that code does not need any list ;)
still, you need to adjust the formulas by one day to in/exclude the actual day (so if it is the `16th Jan`, is it still `2` or allready `3`?)